# OpenSSL implementation of Shamir Secret Sharing

Tags: c, openssl, shared-secret

I'm attempting to implement Shamir Secret Sharing using OpenSSL.  I'm having a lot of trouble getting the message to decrypt!

I have tried several implementations for decryption, both this one: 
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs754/2001fa/307.pdf

And this one (which references the paper above, but uses a different method):

[image: http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a60/cacollo/confused1.jpg] (Note i am aware of the typo for calculating `u2`)

I believe my problem might be a loss of precision when doing the Lagrange Interpolation on ik/(ik-ij) using BIGNUM values to represent the key numbers.  I wrote a small function that converts an `int` like a key number to a BIGNUM value.

I'll spare you my key generating code because i'm pretty certain that's working correctly.  The following is my implementation of the JPEG that i linked (not the PDF):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    aij[i] = BN_new();
    BN_mod_exp(aij[i], c.c1, key[i].key, p, ctx);
}


BIGNUM *ik = BN_new();
BIGNUM *ij = BN_new();
BIGNUM *denomTmp = BN_new();
BIGNUM *numTmp = BN_new();
BIGNUM *divTmp = BN_new();
BIGNUM *accum = BN_new();

int j, k;

/* Lagrange Interpolation */
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    BN_one(accum);
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if(j == k) continue;
        else {
            ik = int2BN(key[k].keynum); //int2BN is my function for converting ints to BNs
            ij = int2BN(key[j].keynum);

            BN_sub(denomTmp, ik, ij);

            BN_div(divTmp, NULL, ik, denomTmp, ctx);
            BN_mul(accum, accum, divTmp, ctx);
        }
    }
    cij[j] = BN_new();
    BN_mod(cij[j], accum, q, ctx); // accum % q = cij[j]
}

// Now for the second half...
int a;
u1 = BN_new();
BIGNUM *u1tmp = BN_new();
BN_one(u1);
for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    BN_mod_exp(u1tmp, aij[a], cij[a], p, ctx);
    BN_mod_mul(u1, u1, u1tmp, p, ctx);
}
```

When i spit out the calculated values in cij[], i'm getting: 2, -5, 0 when using keys [2, 4, 5].  According to some math i did by hand it should actually be 10/3, 5, and 8/3.  Is there any way to get around this?

Are there other problems with my code that you see?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be doing modular arithmetic when you do sub, div, mul. i.e. BN_mod_sub, BN_mod_inverse on the denominator, and BN_mod_mul.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I did what you suggested but am still having issues decrypting.  With no other changes i did:

    ik = int2BN(key[k].keynum);
    ij = int2BN(key[j].keynum);

    BN_mod_sub(denomTmp, ik, ij, q, ctx);

    BN_div(divTmp, NULL, ik, denomTmp, ctx);
    BN_mod_inverse(divTmp, divTmp, q, ctx);
    BN_mod_mul(accum, accum, divTmp, q, ctx);   (Sorry, i can't get formatting to work!)

Comment: I also checked my key generator to make sure i was doing all modulus calculations...i wasn't, but it didn't solve my problem.  I can post the key splitter if need be.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a div at all, instead you mod mul ik by the inverse of the denominator.

Comment: Ohhhhh, i see now. I was confused by why i needed the mod_inverse!  I made this change but it did not fix my problem.  I will review all of my code again and see if i can find other errors.  Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

BN_div is an integer division.

For Lagrange you need to do a modular invert then multiply.

Comment: I guess this is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but Frank answered it correctly 3 months ago.